# exported CSV file is empty MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

im exporting my file as a .CSV ,it contains data,but when I open the exported CSV file ,its empty,i don't know where is going wrong,my controller is like the following:

```
 var eventResult = (from c in DB.Events
                 where (c.m_turbine_id == turbineid.turbineID) && (c.m_time_stamp >= frmDate && c.m_time_stamp <= toDate)

                 select new EventLogPartialViewModel
                 {
                     Timestamp = c.m_time_stamp,
                     Description = c.m_event_log_description,
                     WindSpeed = c.m_wind_speed,
                     RPM = c.m_rpm,
                     Power = c.m_power
                 }).ToList();
```

Here is the part im preparing for export:

```
 var excludeTag = DataTag.NoExclusion;

        byte[] csvBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CSVExport.GetCsv(eventResult.ToList(), excludeTag));
    return this.File(csvBytes, "text/csv",".csv");
```

here is my GetBytes method to convert the file:

```
 public static string GetCsv<T>(List<T> csvDataObjects, DataTag excludeTag)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(GetCsvHeaderSorted(propertyInfos, excludeTag));
        csvDataObjects.ForEach(d => sb.AppendLine(GetCsvDataRowSorted(d, propertyInfos, excludeTag)));
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

at the end,i have the values,but the exported file is empty!

My eventResult is a var ,fill with the LINQ,since its a var I need to convert it to string then I can convert to byte using the ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes
the GetCsv does it for me,convert my result to string,as its shown,at the end Im returning a csvBytes as a .csv format ,the size is [8986]bytes,but the exported file which I open it with excel or note is emty

Comment: What is the exact response from the server?  How large is `csvBytes`?  What is `GetCsv()` returning?  What's in `eventResult`?

Comment: @David thanks for the answer,im going to write you the detail I get

Comment: @David {[3960]} bytes

Comment: Just update your question with the answers for @David 's comments

Comment: How do you know the exported file is empty? What are you opening it with?

Comment: @MarkC. I added more explanation on my question

Comment: @David that's all I know,i added more explanation

Comment: @MartinBrown updated my question,i open it via excel or notepad

Comment: So you are saying that the csvBytes variable has 8986 bytes when you return return this.File from your controller. If so this should work. I'd split the line that generates csvBytes into two so you can check that GetCsv is returning a sensible CSV string rather than a load of blank lines. If that isn't it, I would crack out Fiddler and see what is actually being sent in the HTTP response. Also did you check that there are no firewalls, proxys or virus scanners that might be causing funny issues on the wire?

Comment: @MartinBrown what do you mean by splitting?

Comment: @moris1983: You're going to have to debug this further.  Any line of code that has multiple operations, the result of which you have no confirmed, you'll need to split that line into multiple ones of code with one operation each.  Confirm the results of every operation in the code.  Trace to where the problem *first* manifests.  If the resulting value of `csvBytes` itself has been confirmed, switch over to your browser's debugging tools.  Examine the exact response from the server.  You have to narrow down where the problem is happening.

Comment: @moris1983 I simply meant this so that you can stick a watch on csvString and check its contents.     string csvString = CSVExport.GetCsv(eventResult.ToList(), excludeTag);
            byte[] csvBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csvString);

Comment: @MartinBrown thanks for the hint, my "eventResult" is a Var, im converting it to string by string testResult = string.Join(",",eventResult); then I use  byte[] csvBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(testResult); and now I have the result in Csv,I have data,but the only problem is they are not in a right order,as they should be like in a grid